# How to add button in particular form using Ribbon Workbench in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I need to add Button in particular form using Ribbon workbench in CRM so how to do this?

Screen shot is show below , when i click campaign in navigation pane , i need "Add to Campaign" button in Ribbon.

[image]

But i am not getting "Add to Campaign" button.

How to get this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a very nice tool to edit the ribbon which is called Visual Ribbon Editor: http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in the Ribbon Workbench you'll need to:
1. Create a solution that contains the 'Campaign' entity
2. Load the solution into the the Ribbon Workbench.
3. Select the 'Campaign' entity in the 'Entities' panel.
4. Select the 'Sub Grid' ribbon using the drop down in the top right of the design surface.
5. You can add your button to the ribbon here and it will appear on Campaign sub-grids.

hth,
Scott

Comment: yeah thanks Scott.its working fine.
So after adding , how to provide Link for that button? If that button is clicked , i want to navigate to new Custom Entity form. How to do this?